# How can I offset a layered bar chart in altair?

Tags: altair

I have created a layered bar chart that is almost perfect. However as you can see in the picture I have included, the green bars go right over the labels of the stacked bar chart. I know I can shift the text up with dy, however I would also like to shift the green bar downwards. Is this possible?

Another option would be to have the stacked bars and the green bar next to each other instead of overlapping but I am not sure how that would work either.

I am using this code to generate the graph:

```
stacked_base = alt.Chart(df_melted).encode(
        y=alt.Y('Community:N').sort(None),
        x=alt.X('value:Q').stack('zero'),
        order=alt.Order('variable:N',sort='ascending')
    )

stacked_bars = stacked_base.mark_bar(stroke='#141e4d').encode(
        color=alt.Color('color', scale=None)
    )

stacked_text = stacked_base.mark_text(dx=-12).encode(
    text = alt.Text('value'),
    color=alt.Color('text_color', scale=None)
)

alt.layer(
    stacked_bars,
    stacked_text,
    alt.Chart(df).mark_bar(size=10).encode(
        x='Appointments_Kept',
        y=alt.Y('Community').sort(None),
        color='Division',
    ),
).properties(height=1080,width=1920)
```

[image: Layered bar chart]